# Connecting with Portainer: "resource is online but isn't responding to connection attempts"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking, iptables, portainer

I installed Ubuntu on an older Laptop. Now there is Docker with Portainer running and I want to access Portainer via my main PC in the same network. When I try to connect to Portainer via my Laptop where it is runnig (not Localhost address) it works fine. But when I try to connect via my PC, I get a timeout. Windows diagnostics says: "resource is online but isn't responding to connection attempts". How can I open Portainer to my local network? Or is this a problem with Ubuntu?

Comment: Nvmd. I tried using ssh now. It doesn't work either. I did the firewall permission.

Answer (score 0):

so check if you have openssh server running for ssh! disable firewall on terminal `sudo ufw disable`  check if your network card is running on name eth0 `ifconfig` if not change following this step below

Using netplan which is the default these days. File `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` file. but b4 you need to get serial/mac

Find the target devices mac/hw address using the lshw command:

```
lshw -C network
```

You'll see some output which looks like:

```
root@ys:/etc# lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: eth0
       serial: dc:a6:32:e8:23:19
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bcmgenet driverversion=5.8.0-1015-raspi duplex=full ip=192.168.0.112 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

So then you take the serial

dc:a6:32:e8:23:19

Note the set-name option.

This works for the wifi section as well.
if you using calbe you can delete everything add the example only change for your serial "mac" `sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` file.

```
 network:
        version: 2
        ethernets:
            eth0:
                dhcp4: true
                match:
                    macaddress: <YOUR MAC ID HERE>
                set-name: eth0
```

Then then to test this config run.

```
netplan try
```

When your happy with it

```
netplan apply
```

reboot you ubuntu

after restart

stop portainer container

```
sudo docker stop portainer
```

remove portainer container

```
sudo docker rm portainer
```

now run again on the last version

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 \
    --name=portainer --restart=always \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v portainer_data:/data \
    portainer/portainer-ce:2.13.1
```